# How to add data with image in response

Tags: java, servlets, httpresponse

I want to send userid with image in response. I am using httpServletResponse class for that.
This is my code.
I am adding data in header and image in regular body..But I want data with image in body.I dont want to add in header. Is this possible?

```
bytes = objUserMaster.getProfilePicture();
 responseImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
 out = response.getOutputStream();
 response.addHeader("Hiiiiiii", "message");
```

Comment: Why would you want this? It's not standard and just makes it harder for the client to parse.

Comment: so the thing I have done is ok??(In my code)

Comment: Sure, except you haven't written the bytes to the response.